# How to split a string in javascript by special char \

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I believe that this is simple and I'm missing something. I want to split a physical path in windows with javascript. So I try with `String#split` function, but my result was inespected.

For this string

```
"C:\CLC\VIDA\Web\_REPOSITORIO\Colectivos\ReembolsosWeb\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"
```

I'm getting this result

```
var test = "C:\CLC\VIDA\Web\_REPOSITORIO\Colectivos\ReembolsosWeb\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf";

test.split("\"); //throws error
test.split("\\"); //result in -> ["C:CLCVIDAWeb_REPOSITORIOColectivosReembolsosWebTMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"]
test.split(/\\/); // -> the regex is the same as above
```

One last thing, in my test, I found that to get the result that I want I could do it like this

```
var test2 = "C:\\CLC\\VIDA\\Web\\_REPOSITORIO\\Colectivos\\ReembolsosWeb\\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"
test2.split("\\"); // -> ["C:", "CLC", "VIDA", "Web", "_REPOSITORIO", "Colectivos", "ReembolsosWeb", "TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"]
```

So my question is, how can I split the string from `test` var to get the array from the last case?

Comment: splice is used to cut elements out of an array. Split is what you want to use

Comment: Sorry, I'm using split, just a typo :P

Comment: The problem is that your `test` variable actually **doesn't contain** backslash since it has special meaning (used as character modifier). That's why you can't get backslashes from this string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings in javascript support escape sequences via the backslash (`\`). For example if you need a tab in your string you can add a `\t` anywhere in your string and it will be replaced with a tab, a `\n` will be replaced with a new line.

The backslashes in `test` are either converted to their respective characters or dropped because they are invalid escape sequences.

To get around this you can escape one backslash with another to get a single normal backslash. The downside is that this cannot be done in javascript. Generally I paste my string in to notepad/N++/Code/Sublime and replace all `\` with `\\`

Since you are hard coding the string you need to escape all backslashes. After that you can use `test.split("\\")` which, itself contains an escaped backslash.

So, as far as Javascript is concerned, your code looks like this.

```
var test = "C:CLCVIDAWeb_REPOSITORIOColectivosReembolsosWebTMP_011906169_01_01.pdf";
```

To make javascript see the string correctly you need to make it look like this...

```
var test = "C:\\CLC\\VIDA\\Web\\_REPOSITORIO\\Colectivos\\ReembolsosWeb\\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf";
```

Comment: So, my only solution is to add a `\\` to the my string?

Comment: The solution is to double all backslashes. As a simple test do `console.log(test)`, you will see that your string is already broken. After you double the backslashes it should appear normally :)

Comment: Formally it is **not malformed**, it's just has another meaning, not what the OP expects.

Comment: But how could I _remake_ my string in javascript, if I can't know where there is a backslash?

Comment: Javascript cannot be aware of the single backslashes because it is interpreting them as the start of an escape sequence. You just have to double them up manually (or do replace all in the text editor of your choice)

Comment: @hindmost Sorry, you are right. I updated my answer to be a little bit clearer

Comment: @Below the Radar _you will see that your string is already broken._ It depends on what do you exactly mean by "broken". If you mean any issue, that's wrong. There is no issue (error) at all. Just another meaning of the string, not what the OP expects.

Comment: @Below the Radar her*, and sorry, I didn't realize that was why you quoted part of my comment. I can't edit it now but I removed the broken/malformed bits from my answer and reworded it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

> **Firstly**, note that when you have a single backslash in a string, it is used for escaping the next character. It is just ignored if there is no special character next to it to escape.

Now, just have a look at your string :

```
var test = "C:\CLC\VIDA\Web\_REPOSITORIO\Colectivos\ReembolsosWeb\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"
```

Don't you think all of your single backslashes will be ignored here?

So, the solution is simple, what you have already tried successfully. To escape all your backslashes with another backslash.

```
var test2 = "C:\\CLC\\VIDA\\Web\\_REPOSITORIO\\Colectivos\\ReembolsosWeb\\TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"
test2.split("\\"); // -> ["C:", "CLC", "VIDA", "Web", "_REPOSITORIO", "Colectivos", "ReembolsosWeb", "TMP_011906169_01_01.pdf"]
```

> **But, are you worried about any dynamic data which has such backslash?** (For example, coming from a text input or a file input.) Don't think about escaping the backslash inside it. Because you don't need to do that! It's already a well formatted string for you, which you can use as it is. You need to escape only when you are hard coding the string yourself.

Comment: Good point at the end. I wanted to include that in my answer but I couldn't think of a good way to word it.